# question about notation of Bayes theorem

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

i was reading [Yarin's thesis](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/yarin.gal/website/thesis/thesis.pdf)  on Bayesian neural networks and MC-dropout and , at  section 2.1 at page 18, I stumbled upon this formula

$$  p(\bf{w}|\bf{X},\bf{Y})= \frac{p(\bf{Y}|\bf{X},\bf{w})p(\bf{w})}{p(\bf{Y}|\bf{X})}$$

where $\bf{X},\bf{Y} $ is the training set and

$$  p(\bf{Y}|\bf{X})= \int p(\bf{Y}|\bf{X},\bf{w}) p(\bf{w}) \,dw   $$
is the model evidence.

Now my doubt concerns the notation, because I expected to see

$$  p(\bf{w}|\bf{X},\bf{Y})= \frac{p(\bf{Y},\bf{X}|\bf{w})p(\bf{w})}{p(\bf{Y},\bf{X})}$$

but i also understand that the $\bf{Y}= f^{\bf{w}}(\bf{X})$, so it makes sense to put $ \bf{X}$  together with the weights $\bf{w}$ at the right in the first term at the numerator.

is it just a notation thing or am i missing some mathematical passage that allows to pass from one form to the other one?

Comment: The key here is that $\bf{X}$ is not a random variable - it's the feature set - so everything is conditional upon it.  Note also that multiplying both the numerator and denominator of your first equation by $\bf{p(X)}$ "unconditions" the equation on $\bf{X}$ and results in your last equation, but obviously we can just cancel $\bf{p(X)}$ from both the numerator and denominator and remain with the first form.

Comment: ahh right, thanks

Comment: Because "conditional on" a feature set has a different mathematical meaning than conditioning of random variables, both the language and the notation are unfortunately overloaded.

Comment: @whuber hi, i was thinking again about your answers and i was wondering if you knew some sources where i could learn more on the difference you mention